# Export as .obj and .jpg

Tags: export

I was wondering if anyone could please help me figure out how to export my work from blender. 
I made a snowman in blender render and want to export it. The issue is, I would like to be able to export it as a combination of a jpeg and Obj files rather than a .mtl and a .obj. Is this possible? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks! (I also tried to use textures to give the snowman colors instead however wasn't sure how to bake them to allow me to export as a jpg and obj.

Comment: OBJ export is exclusively concerned with exporting geometry only, some and basic material properties are exported too, but in all honesty you shouldn't bother much with those. Actual materials should be remade in the destination application anyway. As for the textures they have nothing to do with OBJ exporting, either reuse the same image based textures you already used in Blender, or if you use procedural ones then bake them to a texture. You can then save the image in whatever format suits you best (be it JPGE, PNG, TGA or otherwise)

Comment: Also see related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Answer (score 1):

When you want to export an obj file with jpeg textures, simply create jpg textures first.

*.mtl is no image format. A Obj file is made of two parts. The *.obj part contains the mesh data. The *.mtl part contains material settings for a primitive phong shader, including the texture paths. You should not leave the *.mtl part away, it is part of the obj file. And when you leave it away then the textures are not found.

So when you export an obj file with jpg textures, then you should end in three parts. The *.obj file, the *.mtl file, and the *.jpg file.

(As a side note, Jpg is the worst texture format you can choose. It uses a lossy compression. You loose quality. I prefer PNG)